# How to get 'UseContextKey' in ajaxcontroltoolkit?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Friends, I've been trying to use 'UseContextKey' while using ajaxcontroltoolkit, but this option is not coming for me. I'm using .net 4.0. Can you suggest any solution? Even I'm not geting 'FirstRowSelected'! Any idea which version to use?

Comment: I assume you are talking about one of the controls?  Which one, where is FirstRowSelected defined?  We need some more information to be able to help.

Comment: @BrianMains thanks. I want a auto complete text box whose functionality will be to dispaly matching data(fetching from database) when I'll start writing something in that text box. This functionality has one more criteria and that is this fetching data may be name, company name, city, address etc. For this I've a web method which takes 3 parameters(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey). I want to send the criteria value through 'contextKey'. Is it possible to do or how to use ContextKey of ajaxcontroltoolkit?

Answer (score 1):

The AutoCompleteExtender has a client-side version of context key; it has the [server version as mentioned here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx), but you can do this in client JavaScript to change the context key:

```
var autoComplete = $find("<%= autoComplete.ClientID %>");
autoComplete.set_contextKey("ABC");
```

Comment: thanks,let me check if it's possible to send my desired value through contextKey.

Comment: No,I've not been able to pass the value.

Comment: Can you post some of that code?  I looked up the markup and see a set_contextKey(value) method... so it should work.  Just make sure UsecontextKey is set to true on the extender.